# javascript and seo

Tags: javascript, seo, client-side

I have a javascript snippet that clients can put on their webpages that loads some text associated with embedded flash objects (like Slideshare presentations) on that page. Does Google crawl this type of content? Will this provide any SEO benefit?  If not, what else should I consider.  I don't want to force people to embed the actual content since they typically have multiple pages that use this script and the there is typically a lot of text.  Any suggestions?

Comment: If you want the proper effect embed it on every page.

Answer (score 3):

google does execute on page javascript quite well, but the current seo consensus is that external javascript (i.e.: asynchronous loaded content )does not count as part of the page.

this means, that script (the loaded text) is not seo valuable.

if you want the text to be valuable it must be onpage, means it must be in the html of the page, so basically you will have to go with the big (text already included) js snippet.

but before you rush to make it "seo-valuable"e please be aware that duplicate content is usually not valuable. so if the text shows up on different pages it might not be useful to include the text at all.

Answer (score 2):

Flash is popular on the Web, but each presents challenges to the search engines in terms of indexing the related content. This creates a gap between the user experience with a site and what the search engines can find on that site.

It used to be that search engines did not index Flash content at all. In June 2008, Google announced that it was offering improved indexing of this content

### [(http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2008/06/improved-flash-indexing.html).](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2008/06/improved-flash-indexing.html)

This announcement indicates that Google can index text content and find and follow links within Flash files. However, Google still cannot tell what is contained in images within the Flash file. Here are some reasons why Flash is still not fully SEO-friendly:

Different content is not on different URLs
This is the same problem you encounter with AJAX-based pages. You could have unique frames, movies within movies, and so on that appear to be completely unique portions of the Flash site, yet there’s often no way to link to these individual elements.

The breakdown of text is not clean
Google can index the output files in the SWF file to see words and phrases, but in Flash, a lot of your text is not inside clean  or

tags; it is jumbled up into half-phrases for graphical effects and will often be output in the incorrect order. Worse still are text effects that often require “breaking” words apart into individual letters to animate them.

Flash gets embedded
A lot of Flash content is only linked to by other Flash content wrapped inside shell Flash pages. This line of links, where no other internal or external URLs are referencing the interior content, means some very low PageRank/link juice documents. Even if they manage to stay in the main index, they probably won’t rank for anything.

Flash doesn’t earn external links like HTML
An all-Flash site might get a large number of links to the home page, but interior pages almost always suffer. For embeddable Flash content, it is the HTML host page earning those links when they do come.

SEO basics are often missing
Anchor text, headlines, bold/strong text, img alt attributes, and even title tags are not simple elements to properly include in Flash. Developing Flash with SEO in mind is just more difficult than doing it in HTML. In addition, it is not part of the cultural lexicon of the Flash development world.

A lot of Flash isn’t even crawlable
Google has indicated that it doesn’t execute external JavaScript calls (which many Flashbased sites use) or index the content from external files called by Flash (which, again, a lot of Flash sites rely on). These limitations could severely impact what a visitor can see versus what Googlebot can index.

Note that it used to be that you could not test the crawlability of Flash, but the Adobe Search Engine SDK does allow you to get an idea as to how the search engines will see your Flash file.

Answer (score 1):

You can have the content on an external page.

If you don't want Google to crawl it, block it with robots.txt

If you don't want Google to index it (possibly a better option) use x-robots or noindex in the head.

Whether you use javascript to pull it into the page, iframes, or both really comes down to implementation and what the included page may need to access on the page, tracking, sessions etc.

Answer (score 1):

Although google does not crawl flash and java script so well but these are not the only things crucial for SEO. There are many other things which matters such as keyword density, quality of content, inboubd and outbound linking, titles and content should be well managed with proper tags etc. So if flash/java script is necessity then use it but do not use it in excess.

Answer (score 0):

Google is not efficient at reading or indexing flash elements. If I had to publish content like slideshare, I would produce a PDF. This can be indexed with no problem, it could drag traffic to my website.

Answer (score 0):

Google crawls Flash objects to some extent. But in my experience a best solution (if Flash is imminent) is to use SWFObject for alternative HTML text. This will make your Flash and your Site 100% Google friendly and, more importantly, **user** friendly.

For more information go here:
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/alternative_content.html

Answer (score 0):

People read way too much into what Google will think about the technology or specific code they use on their site. If you're on the up-and-up and not using the code to cloak, deceive visitors or hijack sessions...you're going to be just fine. Will you rank better if you subbed all text for Flash? Maybe a little, but at the end of the day it's the quality of your content (yes, even if it's not text-based), the number of people that find it useful (via high quality links) and other small factors.

8 years ago, your answer would have been more valid for not including JS, but it just doesn't matter much anymore, Google treats navigable websites the same and ranks primarily around "quality", not usability excessive keyword rich text.